# How to extract an instance of ObjectTypeA encapsulted in an general object? - screenshot attached

Tags: c#

I am implementing an eventhandler for ObservableCollection of Product.

I have a NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e. e.NewItems[0] returns the first object that has been changed. But this is an object, meaning it is not a Product, the Product is encapsulated in the object somehow, but I am not sure how to extract the Product from this object.

tempPVM is of type "ObjectTypeA" :)

Please refer the following screenshot. :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object *is* the product - it's just not statically typed that way. You can just cast:

```
Product firstNewProduct = (Product) e.NewItems[0];
```